# What does $T$ in the following notation signify? $F = (F_{rot}, F_{tran})^T$? - 2D Car rotation physics

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, notation

I am reading the following [paper](http://entertain.univie.ac.at/~hlavacs/publications/car_model06.pdf) to help me understand 2d car steering physics. In several places the paper shows a notation where a vector is put to the power of $T$. Like so: [image: To the power of Tau]

I am assuming it is related to torque. But am unable to understand why the author is raising this vector to the power of torque. Is this even what it means?

For further context purposes this the paragraph where the author or the paper first uses this notation:
[image: First time article mentions to the power of tau]

Fig. 2:

[image: Figure.2 from the paper]

Comment: The first T looks like the transpose operator, they wrote a column vector as a row vector transposed. The second T appears to be a tau as in torque.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is asking about common notation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063/25301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper see top of the right column above equation 17 on the 4th page:

"whereas point A moves with velocity $$v_A = (\omega L, v)^T$$

Then see figure 5 where $A$ is on the top of the figure, where the vector and its components are shown: $v_A$, $\omega L$ and $v$.

The $T$ is the transpose operator which converts the row vector to a column vector. ( maybe used so it will fit into the line of text as a row vector )